# Is there a way to automatically mail gradle test reports?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gradle

I run the tests on a remote machine on vpn. I don't want to reconnect just to see the reports, can they be mailed to me through gradle?

Comment: Are you running in a CI framework like Jenkins?  I imagine that has options to send results, rather than baking the complexity into your build system itself.

Comment: it's a simple gradle.build file. No additional frameworks. I am pretty much the only one coding this anyway, would Jenkins be an overkill?

Comment: IMHO, no.  Something like Jenkins gives you Git/SVN polling, a complete log of all build/test results, a UI that allows you to drill down into individual test failures and inspect the output trace, etc.  I regularly use it for my "personal" projects.

Comment: sold. Why don't you type this as a full answer so I vote you up?